# Program to find the number of ways of achieving a sum x using y numbers?

Tags: java, math

This is a sub-problem of a problem that I am working on.
A man is standing on the x-axis at 0 and receives a string on his phone to reach his destination.

+means moving 1 unit in the positive direction.

-means moving 1 unit in the negative direction.

The string sent to him and the string he actually receives is distorted by external factors.

The string he actually receives contains a third character which is unreadable by him i.e. '?'. If he reads a ? he takes a random choice to move 1 unit to the right or to the left.

I have to find the probability that the successful man reaches his final destination with the text he received.

For example:

s1 = +-+-

s2 = +-??

s1 evaluates to 0 (1-1+1-1).

s2 can have values (2,0,-2,0)

So the probability that he reaches his destination is 2/4 = 0.5

What I've done till now is calculated the final destination score according to s1 and a temp score according to the +s anf -s in s2 and the difference between both is sum I'm trying to reach.

The question now essentially becomes how many ways can you achieve a sum of x using y 1s and -1s. And calculate probability using that value divided by 2^y.

```
private static double calculateProb(String s1, String s2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
    int num_q = 0, temp = 0;
    int score = 0;

    for(char c: c1){
        if(c=='+')
            score+=1;
        else if(c=='-')
            score-=1;
    }
    for(char c : c2){
        if(c=='+')
            temp+=1;
        else if(c=='-')
            temp-=1;
        else if(c=='?')
            num_q++;
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this a math question or a programming question? --- If math, then you're on the wrong site. Go to https://math.stackexchange.com/. --- If programming, then show the code you've tried. Don't describe it. Show it. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: You have `n` unknowns. Find the number of 1s required to reach your goal, `k`. Your answer is then the binomial coefficient `n choose k`

Comment: I've added the code I've written so far. I'm having a hard time writing the code for getting the `n choose k` part. I know that recursion is one solution but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: See the [integer partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) problem.

Answer (score 0):

> how many ways can you achieve a sum of x using y 1s and -1s

Some corner cases first: If |*x*| > *y* there are zero ways. If *x* is even and *y* is odd, or vice versa, it's zero, too. Otherwise, you need *a* 1s and *b* −1s, with *a*−*b*=*x* and *a*+*b*=*y*. So *a*=(*y*+*x*)/2 and *b*=(*y*−*x*)/2. Then you can arrange these *a* steps in one and *b* steps in the other direction in (*y* !) / (*a* ! × *b* !) ways. This is the number of ways to choose *a* elements out of *y*, computed using a binomial coefficient which is sometimes written *yCa* and pronounced “*y* choose *a*”. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination for further discussion.